# JS Code for simple grade calculator not working

Tags: javascript

Why is my code below for a simple grade calculator not working? I can put in numbers, but after I have done so, no grade is shown on the screen. What am I doing wrong? The Japanese can be ignored. My students are Japanese, so I put the instructions in Japanese.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>英語1B</title>

        <script>
        function computeGrade() {
        var q1=document.getElementById('q1').value;
        var q2=document.getElementById('q2').value;
        var q3=document.getElementById('q3').value;
        var es1=document.getElementById('es1').value;
        var es2 =document.getElementById('es2').value;
        var es3 =document.getElementById('es3').value;
        var a=document.getElementById('a').value;
        var average = ((q1+q2+q3)/192*.25 + (es1+es2+es3)/50*.55 +     a/14*.2)*100);
        document.getElementById('average').innerHTML = "あなたの平均が" +   average + "%。";}



        </script>
        </head>

        <body>
        <h2>成績の計算</h2>

        <p>小テスト1の点数:<input id="q1" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p>

         <p>小テスト2の点数:<input id="q2" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p>

<p>小テスト3の点数:<input id="q3" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p>

<p>エレベーター・スピーチ1の点数: <input id="es1" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p>

        <p>エレベーター・スピーチ2の点数: <input id="es2" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p>

        <p>エレベーター・スピーチ3の点数: <input id="es3" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p>

        <p>出席の回数: <input id="a" type="number" onchange="computeGrade()"></p><br>

         <p id = "average"></p>


         </body>

         </html>
```

Comment: Please provide expected output, an actual output.

Comment: A good place to look is the errors that your browser emits when something goes wrong. You can usually find this by right-clicking somewhere on the page and the inspecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra parenthesis on line 16 of your HTML:

```
// [YOUR CODE] this last parenthesis is not needed.
var average = ((q1+q2+q3)/192*.25 + (es1+es2+es3)/50*.55 + a/14*.2)*100); 

// [YOUR CODE WITHOUT LAST PARENTHESIS] this does not produce any errors.
var average = ((q1+q2+q3)/192*.25 + (es1+es2+es3)/50*.55 + a/14*.2)*100;
```

I found this by copy/pasting your snippet into an html file, and opening up my browser's console output to see where the error was pointing to.

Answer (score 0):

You had 1 unexpected token in your javascript: you should delete the last paranthesis on the line where you are calculating the average

```
var average = ((q1+q2+q3)/192*.25 + (es1+es2+es3)/50*.55 + a/14*.2)*100;
```

I put your code into a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWMwwM